# Fastlane Match / Bitrise / Provisioning Profile mismatch

Tags: fastlane, bitrise, fastlane-match

I'm using Fastlane match in a lane on Bitrise.

The lane correctly runs match, with the output under the heading "Installed Provisioning Profile", saying the installed profile is named: "match Development com.xxx.yyy"

When I check that profile in the App Developer Portal (it's the only profile I've got set up), the name matches, and the portal says "Enabled Capabilities: Associated Domains, Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications").

Yet fastlane gym still reports:

```
error: "<app name>" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains and Push Notifications features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
```

The lane is:

```
lane :ios_build do
    
    match(
        type: "development",
        app_identifier: "com.xxx.yyy",
        git_url: "https://#{ENV['MATCH_GIT_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['MATCH_GIT_PASSWORD']}@gitlab.com/<project>/<repo>.git",
        storage_mode: "git",
        team_id: "<team id>",
        app_identifier: "com.xxx.yyy",
        readonly: true
    )

    disable_automatic_code_signing(path: "/Users/vagrant/git/src-cordova/platforms/ios/xxx.xcodeproj")
    
    build_app(
        scheme: "<scheme name>",
        workspace: "/Users/vagrant/git/src-cordova/platforms/ios/xxx.xcworkspace"
    )
    
    enable_automatic_code_signing(path: "/Users/vagrant/git/src-cordova/platforms/ios/xxx.xcodeproj")
    
end
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Andy

Comment: Any updates on this? Facing the same issue

Comment: Nope, I gave up.